# how to find the 'n' term in fibonacci sequence?

Tags: c++

So i need help with finding a certain term in the fibonacci sequence. I have a program that is pretty close to it, but it will always find the term before the one i actually want.For example, if i want to show the 12th term it will show 89 instead of 144. This is also based on user input, so the user will choose what term to display. Heres the program i have.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float fibSequence(float x);

int main(){
  int x;
  cout << "Term in fibonacci number: ";
  cin >> x;
  cout << "Fibonacci term: " << fibSequence(x) << endl;
}

float fibSequence(float x){
  int prev = 1;
  int prev2 = 0;
  int current = x;
  for(int i = 2; i <= x; i++){
    current = prev + prev2;
    prev = prev2;
    prev2 = current;
  }
  return current;
}
```

And for the life of me i cannot figure out why. Like always, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: 0 is really the first term in the sequence making the 12th term 89.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your assignment order. It should be:

```
current = prev + prev2;  
prev2 = prev;  
prev = current;
```

**edit:** 
you could also switch the initial values:

```
int prev = 0;
int prev2 = 1;
```

but i assume `prev2` is meant to be 'older' than `prev`

Comment: wow, it was right in front of my face the whole time! thanks for pointing out that error, that did the trick!